# trying to get a list of events from a calendar using PHP

Tags: php, google-api, google-calendar-api

I am trying to get a list of events from a calendar.
i am looking at 
developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/calendarList/list

I assume that $service is created from $cal = new apiCalendarService($client); The doc is not very specific.

when i try to execute the code below , i get the error 
PHP Fatal error: Call to a member function getItems() on a non-object

but if i do this it works

```
$calendarList = $cal->calendarList->listCalendarList();
print "<h1>Calendar List</h1><pre>" . print_r($calendarList, true) . "</pre>";
```

Also if i try the example code @

developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/list#examples
I get the same kind of error
PHP Fatal error: Call to a member function getItems() on a non-object

This works:

```
$events = $cal->events->listEvents('rtparies@gmail.com');    print "<h1>Events</h1><pre>" . print_r($events, true) . "</pre>";[/PHP]
```

This fails:

```
foreach($events->getItems()as $event){
echo $event->getSummary();
```

}

I can not imagine all these examples are bad, so any suggestions on what i am doing wrong?

The example is below :

```
$calendarList = $service->calendarList->listCalendarList();
while(true){
  foreach($calendarList->getItems()as $calendarListEntry){
      echo $calendarListEntry->getSummary();
   }
  $pageToken = $calendarList->getNextPageToken();
  if($pageToken){
      $optParams = array('pageToken'=> $pageToken);
      $calendarList = $service->calendarList->listCalendarList($optParams);
  }else{
      break;
  }
}
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: can you please use `var_dump($cal)` and `var_dump($calendarList)` in order to check if they are objects.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to get `$calendarList` as an Object, not Array as your current code does.

Use

```
$client->setUseObjects(true);
```

just before

```
$service = new apiCalendarService($client);
```

Explanation:

```
$events = $cal->events->listEvents('rtparies@gmail.com');
```

returns an Array. This would be OK, if you wouldn't need an object for further processing.

Since you need an object, you need to set the use of objects to true:

```
$client->setUseObjects(true);
```

Now,

```
$events = $cal->events->listEvents('rtparies@gmail.com');
```

is still working, only the difference is that you now have an object, which you can use for your code below this line.

Answer (score 0):

try to update your code:

```
     foreach($calendarList->getItems()as $calendarListEntry){
    echo '<h1>event->getSummary()='.$event->getSummary().'</h1>';
    $client->setUseObjects(true);   
    $events = $cal->events->listEvents($event->id);
    echo 'events=<pre>'; print_r($events); echo '</pre>';       
 }
```